# UIScrollView initial offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have created a UIScrollView using storyBoard. I wanted to add few labels and buttons in that. At very first time, when I add label using following method it is not visible.

```
int _x=0,_y=0;
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_x,_y, stringsize.width, stringsize.height)];
```

But, When I set _y position as -62 then it is visible as expected.

I have tried to invoke following methods before adding label to UiScrollView to fix this issue. But nothing works.

```
[scrollview.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollview.frame.size.width, 0);
[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
```

Basically the issue is during first time launch of UIscrollView the Y position is not set properly.

Comment: check your scrollview.contentSize.

Comment: The ViewController has some different properties for layouts, it might be "Adjust Scroll View Insets" or another that might screw things up.

Comment: After disabling "Adjust Scroll View Insets"option in storyboard. It is working as expected. Thanks Finn!

Comment: @user1743514 : if you have got your answer, please submit it in answer and accept is so that question is marked as "Answered" by SO. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After disabling "Adjust Scroll View Insets"option in storyboard. It is working as expected. Thanks Finn! –